# Unity2D world generation errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to create a custom form of world generation for my Unity2D game for a while now, and I've been stuck on one facet of it. The goal is to place a main room, block off certain directions, place rooms in non-blocked-off areas, and then prevent the new room from blocking off the previous room. Where it goes haywire is when two offshoots of the main room try to place a room on the same spot. I have code to destroy the second room that's placed, which works, but adding one of the blockers to the first room doesn't. I've tried a couple different methods and the current seems to get me the closest to success.
The main snippet of code that is most likely causing the error is here:

```
        foreach (GameObject room in rooms)
        {
            if (room != this.gameObject && room.transform.position == transform.position) //Checking if any rooms coincide with this room
            {
                if (room.gameObject.name == "Outdoor Room")
                {
                    Destroy(this.gameObject);
                    break;
                }
                if (room.GetComponent<OutdoorRoom>().dir == "U")
                {
                    Debug.Log("test");
                    exits += "S";
                }
                if (room.GetComponent<OutdoorRoom>().dir == "D")
                {
                    Debug.Log("test");
                    exits += "N";
                }
                if (room.GetComponent<OutdoorRoom>().dir == "L")
                {
                    Debug.Log("test");
                    exits += "E";
                }
                if (room.GetComponent<OutdoorRoom>().dir == "R")
                {
                    Debug.Log("test");
                    exits += "W";
                }
                Destroy(room);
            }
        }
```

The whole script is here: https://paste.mod.gg/olewesapik.cs
I can answer any questions you have about this. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: you mention errors, what are the errors?

Comment: PS repeated calls to getcomponent should be avoid where possible to speed up  game

Comment: Not any errors, actually. Should've said bugs. I'll exchange GetComponent for something more efficient. The code runs fine, it just doesn't run the way I want it to run.

Comment: Please explain the issue.  I’m going to guess it doesn’t notice more than one component. I made a self generating room system I used an array of n,s,e,w and made prefabs with the openings set. Then all I had to do was generate rooms with random exits and if it was an already existing room adjust it to make sense with the new direction.

Comment: The issue in a nutshell is that when I place a room on top of another existing room, I run the function shown in the code. The first if statement makes sure it isn't the base room, which cannot be destroyed. If it isn't, continue. If the room's direction(the direction it was spawned in, U means up, etc.) is a certain irection, open up my exits so I can't place a blocker there, so the path must be opened. The problem stems from not placing the blocker. It still will place a blocker although it is told not to.

Comment: well it looks from your code that you can only set up down left or right per component, as a result, it expects only 1 exit.. repeat calls to get component will almost certainly continue to retrieve the same component, eg the first one..

Comment: So then... how would I fix it? I've never known an alternative to GetComponent, and I don't fully understand what you mean by "one state only." Thanks for pointing out the error though!

Comment: well, given that dir has to equal L, R, U, D it can only be 1 of those, it cant be say all 4.. or 3 of them, or 2.. therefore it has 1 direction only.  Personally, Id have 1 component that handles all 4 options (bools work well), or, you need to use getcomponents and check each one... and add up which exits you need..